# Riding a robot model in Gazebo along a straight, curved path with feedback on a Raspberry running ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, raspberry-pi, trajectory

please be kind and advise how to implement the following: I have a computer with ROS and Gazebo in which I have a robot model in URDF format, I need this model to go on a straight/curved path(straight/ slightly left/right to the side). How can I do this?

Then, when the model is moving straight in Gazebo, I need the Raspberry Pi 3 model B (ROS Noetic is installed on the Raspberry) to light up LED #1, when moving sideways, LED #2 lights up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.